# Which UTM arguments do apply in a multi site setup?

Tags: google-analytics, utm-tracking

I have two sites (**`Site A`** and **`Site B`**) on two domains. On both sites the same GA tracking code is set up and on **`Site A`** the "linker" is enabled for multi site tracking as explained [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342).

**`Site A`** is a landing page while **`Site B`** is the page where the product can be bought.

If a user enters **`Site A`** on

**`https://siteA.com?utm_campaign=foo&utm_source=3rdparty`**

and clicks a link on **`Site B`** with

**`https://siteB.com?utm_campaign=bar&utm_source=siteA`**

Will the `utm_campaign` on the checkout always be "**bar**" or will it be "**foo**"?

Do I have to remove the *utm_** on the link on **`Site A`** to preserve "**foo**" or do I have to rewrite the parameters to keep them?

It should be "**foo**" if the user is coming from the "**3rdparty**" and "**bar**" otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario 'utm_campaign' will be **bar**.

However in cross-domain monitoring **you don't have to use *utm_****, otherwise it doesn't make sense to talk about cross-domain tracking.

Every time you move from one site to another through the *utm*, you stop the current session and generate a new one... while the purpose of cross-domain tracking is to understand how the same session moves between the two sites.

Comment: ok, that's what I like to hear :). So using `utm_` only from third party sites to keep arguments. How about the `_ga` arguments on multi site tracking? Will an `utm_*` still create a new session if `_ga` is passed?

Comment: Keeping _ga between two sites in cross-domain allows you to keep the same user in Analytics, but if the utm parameters change source and medium, a new session is created for that user.

Comment: I see so `_ga` only keeps the user data but not the session. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, it is the clientId, the value in the _ga cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You will see both - "foo" and "bar" - in GA reports, but only "bar" on the checkout because of any new value of utm parameter starts the new session.

In case of cross-domain tracking is set up correctly, to see full path of user from Site A to Site B you should use utm only once: for landing page of Site A.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How can I reveal both? Do you mean because they count as two sessions?

Comment: Yes, 2 sessions.